# passing string as a table type from c# code in to stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I want to pass a table as a string into stored procedure as a parameter and want to retrieve data from that particular table for e.g. I have made some tables which is year wised like purchase20162017,transfer20162017. 
so problem is this i have created a dropdown box in which i have shown the years list like 2016-2017,2017-2018,2018-2019 user select the year from the dropdown box and click a button called generate ledger button. so i take a string from this dropdown box like this

```
string str = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
str = str.Replace(@"-", "");
string purdtb = "purchase" + str;
```

now i have got exact table in purdtb but it is in string, i want to pass this string value as a parameter in stored procedure. Please tell me how to do this so that i can convert this string as a table name.

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL. You can use dynamic SQL in your stored procedure but then you will have to whitelist the table names, or you can **do it the right way**, and fix your *broken* database model by merging all these year-based tables into a signle table (so that `purchase20162017` and `purchase20142015` will become just `purchase`, and add a column to indicate the year.

Comment: can you please give me a example.

Comment: An example of what? I don't know how your database look like or what sql statement you want to execute...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.

**A) The best one is:**

```
string connectionString =
        ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    //
    // In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
    //
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                    reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

In Dogs1 put your table, use variables to modify the query via code. Why you want to put dynamic table names which is pretty awkward in you stored procedures when you can manage everything from the code with a variable?

**B) The second way (not good but works):**

Use in your stored procedure [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), pass the table names as parameters and build the query inside the stored procedure as shown in the documentation and catch the result.

This way you can build the query piece by piece and put in it everything you want (except for SQL reserved keyword, with which you should be careful anyway).

```
declare @SqlString nvarchar(2000)
declare @ParamDef nvarchar(2000)

set @SqlString = N'exec proc1 @param1, @param2, @param3'

set @ParamDef = N'@param1 bit, @param2 bit, @param3 bit'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlString ,@ParamDef, @param1 = 0, @param2 = 1, @param3 = 1
```

To explain, sp_executesql works something like this

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
   N'proc1',                                 -- SQL
   N'@param1 bit, @param2 bit, @param3 bit', -- DECLARE
   @param1 = 0, @param2 = 1, @param3 = 1     -- VALUES
```

Which gets translated to

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
   N'proc1',                                 -- SQL
   N'@param1 bit, @param2 bit, @param3 bit', -- DECLARE
   @param1 = 0, @param2 = 1, @param3 = 1     -- VALUES

-- DECLARE
  declare @param1 bit, @param2 bit, @param3 bit
-- VALUES
  select @param1 = 0, @param2 = 1, @param3 = 1
-- SQL
  proc1
```

**3) Worst scenario:**

Calling sp_executesql from C# code via Sqlcommand

Comment: *Why you want to put dynamic table names which is pretty awkward in you stored procedures when you can manage everything from the code with a variable?* - because it's an open door for sql injection. Care to guess what will happen if someome use `purchase20162017; drop table purchase20162017;--` as the table name? **Using a stored procedure and white listing the table names is safe.** Once the table name is not in the list, you just return an error and not run the query.

Comment: @ZoharPeled not with parametrized queries. What injection you talking about? He manages his code, he builds his queries. We are not talking about an open scenario with user inputs here

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment to the question - you **can't** parameterze identifiers in SQL. This leaves you with only 3 options - 1. do the right thing and change the database structure,  2. do the second best and use dynamic sql while white listing the identifiers, 3. do the worst possible thing and concatenate strings in c# to create an unsafe SQL statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled how you can't? sp_executesql let you do it and I remember I did this in the past. And I remember also Entity framework allows you to do it

Comment: Try to run `DECLARE @t sysname = N'Dog1';EXEC sp_ExecuteSql N'SELECT * FROM @t', N'@t sysname', @t`. You will get an error - *Must declare the table variable "@t".*